# Laravel Nova template customization

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I started to do some tests on the new administration panel Laravel Nova. I read the documentation and didn't find any mention of how we can do some template customization.

Anybody can explain how the template engine works? It's there any way to override some pages components output?

How do I need to proceed if I want to change the logo or the footer, or the navbar **WITHOUT** modifying the originals files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After publishing nova, a new folder named "nova" should have been created under `resources/views/vendor/`. The logo file should already be there.

If not, create it. You can look into `nova/resources` for the filenames.

After that you can simply create a file named the same way as another template in `nova/resources/views` and it will load the proper one.

From there you can override the vue-router and add your js and css.

So your resources folder path for the logo file would look something like this

`resources/views/vendor/nova/partials/logo.blade.php`

Comment: FYI, I suggested to add this information on the documentation -> https://github.com/laravel/nova-docs/issues/74 if you think this is important too, please don't hesitate in making a thumbs up ;)